# how to add a code to exit this zeromq example by press keyboard q button

Tags: haskell, zeromq

http://zguide.zeromq.org/hs:asyncsrv

hope to terminate the program by press q to exit

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    runZMQ $ do
        async $ clientTask "A"
        async $ clientTask "B"
        async $ clientTask "C"
        async serverTask

        liftIO $ threadDelay $ 5 * 1000 * 1000
```

Comment: You will have to use Software Transactional Memory structure in a separate thread with a `MVar`. The `MVar` starts with no value and is shared between threads. In the separate thread, block until `'q'` is pressed and place a token in the `MVar`. In your working thread you will poll at each recursive step if the `MVar` has a value.

Comment: could you post this code directly, i do not know the syntax and which library or function should be used. Moreover, how to stop the zeropmq in haskell?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no prior attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: You may want to **read whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community**, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far.** You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 1):

### Process-to-process message passing is the very power of the ZeroMQ, so use it:

1. design a central **`aKbdMONITOR`**-thread, that monitors Keyboard and scans for <kbd>**`Q`**</kbd> | <kbd>**`q`**</kbd>

> ```
> async $ clientTask "C"
> async $ aKbdMONITOR                    -- Add central-service async thread
> ```

2. equip this `aKbdMONITOR`-thread with a **`PUB`** service to broadcast to any **`SUB`**-side an appearance of such event

> ```
> aKbdSCANNER <- socket Pub              -- PUB-side adequate ZeroMQ Archetype
> bind aKbdSCANNER "tcp://*:8123"        -- yes, can serve even for remote hosts
> ```

3. equip all other threads with a **`SUB`** pattern part and review any subsequent arriving event-notification from `aKbdMONITOR`-thread to decide locally about self-termination in case `aKbdMONITOR`-thread announces such case as requested above to exit

> ```
> aKbdSCANNER <- socket Sub              -- SUB-side adequate ZeroMQ Archetype
> connect aKbdSCANNER "tcp://ipKBD:8123" -- tcp transport-class remote ipKBD
> --
> -- + do not forget to subscribe
> -- + use poll to scan
> ```